# Working with a QueryString and placing value in Stored Procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am working with ASP.NET and SQL Server 2005.

I know how to create a stored proceudre but i do not know what to place in a stored procedure when i need to make use of a QueryString.

My SQL Statement in CODE =

```
"SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ID = '" + Request.QueryString("ID") + "'"
```

Now what must i place in my stored procedure to get this to work? I want to call a stored procedure and thus do not want to use this code in my code behind.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how u calling ur stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this problem is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530906/reading-a-stored-proc-not-working-for-me-when-passing-values)

Answer (score 1):

Create an sqlcommand object

set the commandtext = "StoredProcName"

add an sqlParameter with the name of your sproc parameter - set its type

set its value to Request.QueryString("ID")

check this out for full instructions:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306574

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("yourstoredproc", con);
mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourparam", Request.QueryString["ID"]);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = mycommand;
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataset);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("storedprocedure_name",con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameter_of-procedure",Request.QueryString"ID"]);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = mycommand;
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataset);


//using sqldatareader
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("yourstoredproc", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameters_of_procedure",Request.QueryString["ID"]);
con.open()
sqldatareader dr=cmd.executereader();
gridview1.datasouce=dr;
gridview1.databind();
con.close();
```

Comment: Hi, i am not using a gridview, i am populating text boxes