# Reading a Stored Proc not working for me when passing values

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

Why is this not working for me? What is wrong with my code below? I am trying to read a stored proc and applying values to labels. Getting error that say "Incorrect syntax near CareerInner".........

```
   Private Sub LoadData()

    ' Define data objects
    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Dim Comm As SqlCommand
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    conn = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)


    Comm = New SqlCommand( _
        ("CareersInner"), conn)

    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Request.QueryString("ID"))

    conn.Open()

    reader = Comm.ExecuteReader()

    If reader.Read() Then

        lbltitle.Text = reader.Item("title").ToString
        lbldescription.Text = reader.Item("description").ToString

    End If

     reader.Close()

     conn.Close()

End Sub
```

***Edit:***
My Stored Proc

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CareersInner]



    @ID varchar(10)

     AS
  BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON;


  SELECT * FROM Careers WHERE ID = @ID 

   END
```

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException = {"Incorrect syntax near 'CareersInner'."}

Comment: Is the proc named '"CareersInner"' or '"CareerInner"'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try something like:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(("@ID", Request.QueryString("ID"));
```

Did you try tracing with SQL Profiler?